# Why do I get this error when i turned the website into live

Tags: php, magento, include, magento-1.7

```
Warning: include(Capulus/Customer/Model/Attribute/Source/Typeofcustomer.php)

[function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in 

/home/netbizzc/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

The error is showing when I'm going to `manage customer` and click a `customer`...the errors appear..anybody help me plssss.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your extension problem.

I`ll try to help you. It seems that you have TypeOfCustomer.php file in Source/ folder. If you test you site on windows then everything will be fine b\c TypeOfCustomer.php is equal to Typeofcustomer.php. If you server is Linux then this will be problem with "No such file or directory". Note that linux is case sensitive to filenames.

So, if i am right you need to rename this file on your linux server to Typeofcustomer.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a php expert...but I suggest you use relative paths like:
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/lib/Varien/Autoload.php");
instead of hardcoding the path.

Answer (score 0):

AT first, check if you do really have that file on your server.

Go to Capulus/Customer/Model/Attribute/Source/ and ensure that Typeofcustomer.php exists with the same name as its called within your autoload script.
Let us know if file exists.

Since user344346 already mentioned it could be just a naming convention and you will have to rename your file.

Cheers